# Split name of XML node by capital letter in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<process id="Process_1">
  <exclusiveGateway id="ExclusiveGateway_03b639w" />
  <startEvent id="StartEvent_0nmzsw0" />
  <sendTask id="Task_13s9uob"/>
  <userTask id="Task_1v0riz3" />
</process>
```

I need to convert it to this with **xslt**:

```
<process id="Process_1">
  <Gateway type="exclusive" id="ExclusiveGateway_03b639w" />
  <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_0nmzsw0" />
  <Task type="send" id="Task_13s9uob"/>
  <Task type="user" id="Task_1v0riz3" />
</process>
```

I think I can use `tokenize` function for this but I do not know how to separate tokens.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you mention `tokenize`, does that mean you can use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your answer. But I can use XSLT 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in XSLT 1.0, try something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/process/*">
    <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), $split + 1)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(name(), 1, $split)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that all (and only) children of the root `process` element need to be processed as shown.

---

P.S. If you know the structure of the input XML, it would be more robust to transform the individual elements explicitly, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="exclusiveGateway">
     <Gateway type="exclusive">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </Gateway>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the use of an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[matches(local-name(), '^\p{Ll}+\p{Lu}')]">
        <xsl:element name="{replace(local-name(), '^\p{Ll}+', '')}">
            <xsl:attribute name="type" select="replace(local-name(), '\p{Lu}.*', '')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuNM.