# Processing XSLT codes sequentially

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml like this:

```
 <bpmn:process id="Process_1" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">
    <bpmn:exclusiveGateway id="ExclusiveGateway_03b639w" />
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_0nmzsw0" />
    <bpmn:sendTask id="Task_13s9uob"/>
    <bpmn:userTask id="Task_1v0riz3" />
</bpmn:process>
```

I want to transform it to this xml:

```
<process id="Process_1">
    <Gateway type="exclusive" id="ExclusiveGateway_03b639w" />
    <Event type="start" id="StartEvent_0nmzsw0" />
    <Task type="send" id="Task_13s9uob"/>
    <Task type="user" id="Task_1v0riz3" />
</process>
```

For this I use two XSLT 1.0 codes:

**1-Remove namespaces**

```
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

**2-split node name and add type attribute**

```
<xsl:template match="process/*">
    <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), $split + 1)}">
      <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(name(), 1, $split)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But when I use them together like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>          

    <!-- Step 1 -->    
    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="process/*">
      <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
      <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), $split + 1)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(name(), 1, $split)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

In result, input has not changed!.

Online link for this: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUR

I think xslt does not processing sequentially. 
It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "xslt does not processing sequentially" I think what you are trying to say is that when two template rules match a node, only one of them is applied. That's correct. If you want one template rule to process the output of another, you must capture the output of the first template rule in a variable, and then apply-templates to the variable, preferably in a different mode, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you for your comment. Your opinion is correct. If you reply to my question I accept it.

Comment: @AliSoltani There is no need to have one template rule process the output of another in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. All you need to do is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
exclude-result-prefixes="bpmn">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/bpmn:process/*">
    <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(local-name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), $split + 1)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(local-name(), 1, $split)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or perhaps just (depending upon how different your real input is compared to the example shown):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(local-name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
    <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), $split + 1)}">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(local-name(), 1, $split)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

I repeat my [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38942340/3016153) to address the individual nodes explicitly by their names, if you know them.

Comment: I am trying to say is that when two template rules match a node, only one of them is applied. Please see  Michael Kay comment.

Comment: Also I tested your code but id attributes convert to node value! see http://xsltransform.net/bwdwry

Comment: @AliSoltani As I said, you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. There is no need to apply two template rules sequentially to **any** node in your input.  You can process the input nodes directly in their namespace, without removing the namespace first.

Comment: Yes,there is no need to apply two template rules in this case but If I want to use output of rule in another rule, What should I do?

Comment: If you want to do that, then you'll have to store the output of the first template in a variable and apply the second template to the variable. You can see an example here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471442/applying-xslt-template-one-after-the-other-for-removing-empty-nodes/28473525#28473525 If you need a more detailed answer, post another question with a suitable example (one that *does* require two-step processing).

Answer (score 1):

When you say "xslt does not processing sequentially" I think what you are trying to say is that when two template rules match a node, only one of them is applied. That's correct.

If you want one template rule to process the output of another, you must capture the output of the first template rule in a variable, and then apply-templates to the variable, preferably in a different mode, to avoid confusion.

Comment: michael.hor257k completed your answer in his comments, I think it is better accept him answer for this question. Thank you very much for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have used a namespace `bpmn` in your source XML. I have added a bpmn namespace in the XSL.

Second, In your step 1, you matched `*` and in step 2, you matched `node()`. `node()` matches `*`, `text()`, `comment()`, and `processing-instruction()`. I have modified your step 2.

Third, you should use the `local-name()` function in the `bpmn:process` template match.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:bpmn="www.bpmn.com">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>          

    <!-- Step 1 -->    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- Step 2 -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bpmn:process/*">
        <xsl:variable name="split" select="string-length(substring-before(translate(local-name(), 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'), 'A'))" />
        <xsl:element name="{substring(local-name(), $split + 1)}">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(local-name(), 1, $split)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```